# docker-compose.yml issue getting this error while doing docker-compose up -d on terminal

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.project_name.ports value ['443:443', '7220:7220', '9003:9003', '1110:1110', '5005:5005', '9008:9008', '8800:8800', '8801:8801', '1110:1110', '5005:5005'] has non-unique elements

i am getting this error while doing docker-compose up -d on terminal

Comment: This is a bit short on info but it looks like  you are mapping to ports 1110 and 5005 twice so the error message seems clear - though if this doesn't match what you have in your docker-compose file then you really need to include that in the question in order to get an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something along the following `docker-compose.yml`. As the error tells you, `ports` requires unique mappings but you have defined `"1110":"1110"` and `"5005":"5005"` two times. You simply have to remove the duplicates.

```yaml
services:
  project_name:
    ports:
      - "443":"443"
      - "7220":"7220"
      - "9003":"9003"
      - "1110:1110" # duplicate
      - "5005:5005" # duplicate
      - "9008:9008"
      - "8800:8800"
      - "8801:8801"
      - "1110:1110" # duplicate
      - "5005:5005" # duplicate
```

Comment: (Also `"5005:5005"`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I totally missed this. Thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer.